# a code to input three user-provided statements and solve the questions

Tags: python

A code to input three user-provided statements. Is there any information in the title case?
Total the letters to determine the number. Count up all of the words. What number of words begin with "e"? How many words have "er" at the end? The number of vowels in each of these sentences. Do the statements include any digits? Invert the second assertion. Reverse the third statement's words one at a time.

please solve via python

Answer (score -1):

```
a = input("First statement : ")
b = input("Second statement : ")
c = input("Third statement : ")
al = a.split()
bl = b.split()
cl = c.split()
counte = 0
counter = 0
letter = 0
bll = ""
vowels = 0
ans = 0
ansb = 0
ansc = 0
print(f"The words in first statement is {len(al)}")
print(f"The words in second statement is {len(bl)}")
print(f"The words in third statement is {len(cl)}")
print(f"Total words {len(al)+len(bl)+len(cl)}")
for i in al:
    g = len(i)
    letter += g
    for vow in range(0, len(i)):
        if i[vow] == 'a' or i[vow] == 'i' or i[vow] == 'e' or i[vow] == 'o' or i[vow] == 'u':
            vowels += 1

    if i[0] == 'e':
        counte += 1
    if i[g-1]+i[g-2] == "re":
        counter += 1

for j in bl:
    h = len(j)
    letter += h
    for vow in range(0, len(j)):
        if j[vow] == 'a' or j[vow] == 'i' or j[vow] == 'e' or j[vow] == 'o' or j[vow] == 'u':
            vowels += 1
    if j[0] == 'e':
        counte += 1
    if j[h-1]+j[h-2] == "re":
        counter += 1
for k in al:
    u = len(k)
    letter += u
    for vow in range(0, len(k)):
        if k[vow] == 'a' or k[vow] == 'i' or k[vow] == 'e' or k[vow] == 'o' or k[vow] == 'u':
            vowels += 1
    if k[0] == 'e':
        counte += 1
    if k[u-1]+k[u-2] == "re":
        counter += 1
print(f"The total letters is {letter}")
print(f"The words starting with e is {counte}")
print(f"The words ending with er is {counter}")

# Reversing the second statements
revb = b[::-1]
print(f"The second statement reversed : {revb}")
# Third statement reverse word by word
for words in bl:
    words = words[::-1]
    bll += words+" "
print(f"The third statement reversed word by word : {bll}")
print(f"The total number of vowels is {vowels}")
li = ['0', '1', '3', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
for gh in al:
    for ff in range(len(gh)):
        if gh[ff] in li:
            ans = 967
            print("Numbers are there in first statement ")
            break
for ghk in bl:
    for ffd in range(len(ghk)):
        if ghk[ffd] in li:
            ansb = 9673
            print("Numbers are there in second statement ")
            break
for ghks in cl:
    for fffd in range(len(ghks)):
        if ghks[fffd] in li:
            ansc = 96733
            print("Numbers are there in third statement ")
            break
if ans == 0:
    print(" No Numbers are there in first statement ")
if ansb == 0:
    print(" No Numbers are there in second statement ")
if ansc == 0:
    print(" No Numbers are there in third statement ")

#Code is Completed
```

Comment: Hi TwoplusThree, it would be more helpful to future readers if you also added some exposition explaining what you are doing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).